# sqlite passing comma separated string as sqlite3_result_text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sqlite

I have a custom function that needs to return a comma-separated list of IDs that I then need to use in a statement. However, I can't seem to get it to work as sqlite3_result_text seems to be unhappy about the single quotes I've used for individual strings. Here's what I have:

```
void sqliteExtractNames(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
  assert(argc == 1);

  if (sqlite3_value_type(argv[0]) == SQLITE_TEXT) {
    unsigned const char *stringC = sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);

    NSString *stringOrig = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *) stringC];

    // This returns something like: 'Name 1', 'Name 2'
    NSString *nameString = [self getCommaSeparatedNames: stringOrig];


    if ([nameString length] > 0) {
      sqlite3_result_text(context, [nameString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    } else {
      sqlite3_result_null(context);
    }
  } else {
    sqlite3_result_null(context);
  }
}
```

And then later I'm doing:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM mytable WHERE name IN (sqliteExtractNames(somecolumn))
```

However this does not seem to work. If I change the `getCommaSeparatedNames` method to instead return a single word without single quotes, it works. The moment I use more than one word separated by a comma, it stops working. How can I pass a text result back which can be used in this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `sqliteExtractNames` returns a single string. So your query is the equivalent of:

```sql
SELECT ... WHERE name IN ('aaa,bb,ccc')
```

which check the name against a single string value.

If you have SQLite 3.9.0 or later, you could implement your function as a [table-valued function](http://sqlite.org/vtab.html#tabfunc2), which is rather complex.

Comment: Thanks - yes I realized it's putting a single quote around the whole string. Is there no way to make sqlite return a string 'as-is' without manipulation? I tried using a sqlite3_result_blob to no avail. Table valued functions do indeed look very complex for my needs.

Comment: A 'normal' function returns a single value.